# Java trying to catch not integer user input and make it loop

Tags: java

I was doing my assignment and paycode is one of the variable that let user to key in. So this paycode i declare it as int. So what if the user type other than integer such as a,b,c,d or 1.5,2.5 and so forth. I try the if else function but when user input other than integer there will be error in it. And I wan to make it loop also when user key in paycode other than the integer and let user key in again. This is all I have now and i can't make it loop. Instead, it will turn into infinity loop.

```
int paycode;
boolean good = true;

do {
    try {
        System.out.printf("Key in the paycode of the worker according to the worker type: \n");         
        paycode = myscanner.nextInt();  

        if (paycode == 4 || paycode == 3 || paycode == 2 || paycode == 1) {
            good = false;
        } 
        else { 
            //user key in out of the range of pay code
            System.out.printf("Paycode must be 1,2,3,4 \n");
        }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.printf("Paycode cannot have decimal places. \n");
        System.out.printf("Key in the paycode of the worker according to the worker type: \n"); 
    }   
}       
while (good);
```

Comment: `JavaScript != Java`

Comment: Are you using java or javascript? Your question says javascript, but your code is java.

Comment: Mate this is not Javascript

Comment: thats Java not Javascript

Comment: Oh I misclick the tag because it come out automatically after i finish typing everything and didn't notice it's javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `myscanner` attempts to get the next `int` but the input is invalid, it leaves the invalid input in the buffer when the exception is thrown. You need to add `myscanner.next();` in the `catch` block so that the invalid input is flushed. So, the `catch` block will look like this:

```
...
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.printf("Paycode cannot have decimal places. \n");
    myscanner.next();
}
...
```

Note that you do not need to print `System.out.printf("Key in the paycode of the worker according to the worker type: \n");` in the `catch` block because that would make it print twice whenever there is invalid input.

As an aside, the semantics of your looping are a little confusing. I would set `boolean good = false;` to begin with and then set the while conditional to `while (!good);`. You will also need to change `good = true;` if the input is invalid. This makes it easier to understand why the program is looping (while the input is *not* good). Just a minor suggestion to make your code a little more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i know the wrong path that i did is i type paycode = myscanner.nextInt(); at last line in the catch which cause error in it.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, please accept it. Thanks.